# Understanding Hexadecimal and Memory addresses

Tags: c++, memory-management, hex

Since each single hexadecimal digit corresponds to 4 bits and each byte of memory requires 2 hexadecimal digit, Why the increment in the memory addresses in the code below is happening in the nibbles not the whole byte?

```
#include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    int a , b, c, d;
   
    cout << &a << "\t" <<  &b << "\t" <<  &c << "\t" <<  &d << endl;
  
    cout << (long) &a << "\t" <<   (long)&b << "\t" <<  (long) &c << "\t" <<   (long)&d << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you see in the output below the increment in memory addresses for our int type happened only in nibbles. For example the first increment is from 58 to 5c (4 nibbles from 8 to c) and 4 nibbles is only 2 bytes not 4.

output:

```
0x7ffdc94b6e58  0x7ffdc94b6e5c  0x7ffdc94b6e60  0x7ffdc94b6e64
140727980617304 140727980617308 140727980617312 140727980617316
```

Comment: An int is 4 bytes. The addresses are 4 apart. Its the same 4 apart if you look at the address in hex or decimal

Comment: The addresses are four bytes apart when written in decimal, and of course also four bytes apart when written in hex. Because on your system the size of `int` is four bytes. What did you expect instead?

Comment: what increment? also, c++ does not specify the arrangement of local variables in memory.

Comment: It's worth reading up on [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) and [`alignof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) to better understand. We're well past the [era when addresses stored large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11_architecture), and have coalesced on the idea of addresses referring to 8-bit bytes or "octets". Of course, [not everyone agreed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) on how multi-byte values should be stored, so try not to make any assumptions about their specific layout.

Comment: Tip: Run your code in a debugger to get a better view of what's going on, especially when it comes to memory layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
140727980617304 140727980617308
```

As you can see, the difference between these two addresses is 4. Pointer addresses are, basically, memory addresses. These addresses are 4 bytes apart. Your `int`s take up four bytes long. Hence, consecutive `int`s, stored in memory, will be 4 addresses apart.

> 4 nibbles from 8 to c

You are conflating a term used to describe the representation of a single hexadecimal number with memory addresses.

"nybble" is to hexadecimal is as "digit" is to our natural base-10 number representation.

Whether each particular memory address is presented as a hexadecimal number, consisting of nybbles, or a decimal addresses consisting of digits, makes no difference whatsoever. The above two memory addresses differ by a value of 4, whether you choose to view them as hexadecimal nybbles or decimal digits. The memory addresses are 4 addresses apart. The End.